# Wrong 2nd argument type found 'com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit.Menu_pageFragment' required 'Android.app.Fragment'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have written a code for fragment replacement on click of a send button. But my code shows an error saying

`Wrong 2nd argument type found 'com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit.Menu_pageFragment' required 'Android.app.Fragment'`

in the below line under the word 'newfragment'

`transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);`

When i searched for a solution online it says to extend FragmentActivity instead of extending Fragment. But if i do so then my home_activity (one which has no errors) shows many errors. Can someone please suggest me a solution for this?

Below is my Home_pageFragment in which the sendmessage method replaces it with Menu_pageFragment on click of a send method in its layout:

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class Home_pageFragment extends Fragment {

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
        Menu_pageFragment newFragment = new Menu_pageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt(Menu_pageFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
    }

}
```

Below is my home_page fragment-container code (has no errors):

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Home_page extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        Home_pageFragment firstFragment = new Home_pageFragment();
        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void openSearch() {

    }

    public void openSettings() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Menu_pageFragment :

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Menu_pageFragment extends Fragment {


    public Menu_pageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_page, container, false);
    }


}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you using the support library, or you can use the normal Fragments?

Comment: I am using the v4 support library

Comment: Then, in `Home_pageFragment`, you must use **getSupportFragmentManager** instead of **getFragmentManager**

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() showed me an error. That's y I changed it to getActivity(). getFragmentManager()

Comment: Which also shows you an error....

Comment: In addition, can you please post the code of Menu_pageFragment?

Comment: Yeah i have posted the Menu_pageFragment now... @MarkySmarky

Comment: **getActivity(). getFragmentManager()** doesnot show me an error. But **transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment)** shows an error @Der

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to change a fragment from another fragment...
Try using getChildFragmentManager().

Comment: I have imported all the necessary packages. Is there anything else that i need to import?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't specified which manager and transaction you wish to use.  Instead of hitting just FramentM and then hitting enter when it offers you FragmentManager (or FragmentTransaction as such may be) mouse down the suggested list to where you see FragmentManager/Transaction (android.support.v4.app) and click on it.  The resulting code should look something like this:

```
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Titles_Pane TP = new Titles_Pane();
            ft.add(R.id.title_inflater, TP, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following sentence to your fragement.java files:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```